# Perl mergesort - array reference

Tags: perl, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to implement merge-sort in Perl, I am quite new to Perl and I know I am doing something wrong with the array references. The arrays end up holding the same value after the process is done. Please help cause I don't see where I am going wrong.

The Corrected Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my ( @aref, @auxref ) = ();
my ( $hi, $lo, $i, $j, $k, $n ) = 0;

@aref = ( 5, 7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 9, 4 );
$n = @aref;

mergeSort( \@aref, \@auxref, 0, $n - 1 );

print "@auxref\n";
print "@aref\n";

sub mergeSort {

    my ($aref)   = $_[0];
    my ($auxref) = $_[1];
    my $lo       = $_[2];
    my $hi       = $_[3];

    if ( $hi <= $lo ) { return; }
    my $mid = 0;
    $mid = int( $lo + ( $hi - $lo ) / 2 );
    mergeSort( $aref, $auxref, $lo,      $mid );
    mergeSort( $aref, $auxref, $mid + 1, $hi );

    merge( $aref, $auxref, $lo, $mid, $hi );

}

sub merge {

    my ($aref)   = $_[0];
    my ($auxref) = $_[1];
    my $lo       = $_[2];
    my $mid      = $_[3];
    my $hi       = $_[4];

    for ( $i = $lo ; $i <= $hi ; $i++ ) {
        $auxref->[$i] = $aref->[$i];
    }

    $i = $lo;
    $j = $mid + 1;

    for ( $k = $lo ; $k <= $hi ; $k++ ) {
        if ( $i > $mid ) {
            $aref->[$k] = $auxref->[$j];
            $j++;
        }
        elsif ( $j > $hi ) {
            $aref->[$k] = $auxref->[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        elsif ( $auxref->[$i] <= $auxref->[$j] ) {
            $aref->[$k] = $auxref->[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        else {
            $aref->[$k] = $auxref->[$j];
            $j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sub merge`, you have two array refs: `$auxref` and `$aref`.

And you're accessing the array elements as though they were ordinary arrays (i.e. `$aref[0]`) but as they are array references, you need to dereference with an arrow first: `$aref->[0]`.

Adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script should have weeded out these errors though?

***Arrays***

```
my @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4);
$arr[0] = 5;
push @arr, 6;
# @arr = (5, 2, 3, 4, 6)
```

***Array References***

```
my $arr = [1,2,3];
$arr->[0] = 5;
push @$arr, 6;
# $arr = [5, 2, 3, 4, 6];
```

***2D arrays of array references***

```
my @arr = ([1, 2], [3, 4]);
print $arr[0][1]; # identical to $arr[0]->[1];
push @{$arr[1]}, 5;
# @arr = ([1, 2], [3, 4, 5]);
```

***2D arrayref of array references***

```
my $arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
print $arr->[0][1]; # identical to $arr->[0]->[1];
push @{$arr->[1]}, 5;
# $arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]];
```

***2D Array of arrays***

...can't exist because an array can only hold scalars

```
my @arr = ((1, 2), (3, 4));
# @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: tried that, still didn't work. I have updated the code above.

Comment: adding -> also did not help

Comment: you still have `$auxref[$i] = $aref[$i]` in your `merge` sub. So this is actually referring to the arrays you define on line 4, not the array references that you declare at the beginning of the merge sub.

Comment: Your array references are now good. You have another problem relating to scoping though: you have a lot of variables in the global scope that your subs are (accidentally?) using. E.g. `merge` and `mergeSort` are both using `$mid`, which I expects is causing unexpected results.

Comment: And that's why it's a good reason to place subs before "main" code and/or putting "main" code inside curlies.

Comment: I don't understand, I am setting the value of $mid at the start of every merge function, won't this solve that problem?

Comment: Look at `mergeSort`, you use `$mid` after calling `mergeSort` expecting it to have the same value it had before calling `mergeSort`. It doesn't. Move the declaration of `$mid` to where it belongs.

Comment: `my ( $hi, $lo, $mid, $i, $j, $k ) = 0;` should be deleted. Some of those variables are never used, and the others are declared in the wrong location.

Comment: Just to re-iterate what @ikegami said; try putting all your "main" code into a sub, and calling that sub. Firstly, you'll see a lot of errors about global symbols requiring explicit package names and you'll be forced to declare your variable in the correct places. Once you've done that, you'll find your script works properly.

Comment: Cool it worked, I have put the correct code there now.

Comment: well, you didn't do the main thing you were told ("try putting all your "main" code...) that fixes the root of most of your current and future trouble

Answer (score 0):

The following is a version of [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that doesn't rely on references at all.  It almost certainly isn't as memory efficient as some of the original merge sort algorithms were intended, but it gets the job done.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( 5, 7, 6, 3, 4, 1, 8, 9, 4 );

my @sorted = mergeSort(@array);

print "@sorted\n";

sub mergeSort {
    my @array = @_;

    if (@array > 1) {
        my $mid = int(@array / 2);

        my @lowArray = mergeSort(@array[0..$mid-1]);
        my @highArray = mergeSort(@array[$mid..$#array]);

        # Merge the two halves      
        my @newArray = ();
        while (@lowArray && @highArray) {
            if ($lowArray[0] < $highArray[0]) {
                push @newArray, shift @lowArray;
            } else {
                push @newArray, shift @highArray;
            }
        }

        # Either the low or high array will be empty at this point,
        # so no need to compare for the remainder.
        return (@newArray, @lowArray, @highArray);

    } else {
        return @array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, it would be remiss of us not to mention that Perl's built-in `sort` has been a merge sort since 5.7.

Comment: ...which can be enforeced using `use sort '_mergesort';`

Comment: Re "The following is a version of merge sort that doesn't rely on references at all", You needlessly copy the entire array for each level of recursion to avoid dealing with references. That's a bad thing, not a good thing. You shouldn't be proud of that. My downvote is not just for that, but for not actually helping the OP. He's trying to learn; he's not looking for an implementation (or else he'd just use the builtin `sort`).

Comment: @ikegami The needlessly copying the entire array is exactly why I felt ok posting this version.  It demonstrates a perlish way to implement what he wants (so that he can learn), but doesn't provide the most likely final solution which likely should follow the algorithm more strictly.

Comment: I don't understand. You felt like posting it because you knew it was wasteful? Then why didn't you mention it? What's perlish about that?

Comment: @ikegami The purpose of this exercise is obviously to learn.  Otherwise, one could just rely on perl's built in sort.  He states that he is "quite new to Perl", and obviously had plenty of style errors in his code from attempting to translate the algorithm from another language most likely.  Therefore, I believe there is nothing "wasteful" about demonstrating an alternative way to do it, and at the very least I got use out of refamiliarizing myself with the algorithm.

Comment: I didn't say your post was wasteful; I said your algorithm was. Your post is just wrong. You suggested code as a possible alternative rather than an example of what he shouldn't use. If you had tried to be educational ("here's an alternative version and why you shouldn't use it..."), my comments wouldn't apply, but that's not the route that was taken.

Comment: By your definition, pretty much anything other than perl's builtin sort algorithm is "wasteful".  And you know what?  That's pretty much right!  However, sorts are a good way to learn algorithms in general, and also to learn programming.  I also believe that the code that I showed more clearly demonstrates the method behind a merge sort because it doesn't uses references or do all the memory optimizations that a "real" algorithm would do.  Therefore, if you want to continue thinking of it as wasteful, be my guest, but I believe that misses the point behind a learning exercise.

Comment: Before you start the semantics game, you should reread what I said "You needlessly copy the entire array for each level of recursion to avoid dealing with references." The last part is key. Avoiding basic tools because they're giving you problems is not a good way to learn. And again, neither is simply giving an existing implementation with no explanation whatsoever. No amount of word-play is going to change that.

Comment: I simplified the algorithm for the purpose of teaching and learning, not because references "give me problems".  Anyway, this website just gave the "avoid extended discussion in comments" notice, so if you want to continue this feel free to take it to chat.

Comment: As you noticed, I've been keeping my comments about the answer itself despite all your attempts to start a discussion: Your answer is missing any sort of explanation whatsoever, so it's failing at your intended goal to educate. Take your own advice and fix your answer rather than trying to chat.